# Extending a Webapp - Include user and password

Tags: php, oop, coding-style

They always talk about extendability and flexibility when writing code, but here I am wanting to expand my webapp and I have no idea how to do it.

---

#### What I have:

I have a completed webapp that works similarly to a calendar (though not exactly), a school has a list of teachers, each teacher has a number of tests assigned to him, the school gets a list of possible times for tests, and has to fit the teachers into the possible test times, using several rules. ***That much is DONE***

#### What I want to do:

Now that the application is complete, I recieved a request to support a user/pass system, **and every user will have a specific calendar that matches him** (user == school in this context).

#### The problem:

I want to preform the shift with minimal code alteration (to the source classes). I can extend the source class, but that would mean

1. To change all the times the class is referred to in the code to the new name
2. Simply adding more code

The point is to have each user a database for his own.

***LET ME JUST CLARIFY, MAKING THE USER PASS LOGIN SYSTEM IS NOT THE PROBLEM, THE PROBLEM IS TO EXTEND THE CODE TO ACCOMMODATE THE MULTIPLE USER ENVIRONMENT***

---

### Database Structure:

#### Fixed Tables:

**teachers**

```
id | name
```

#### Monthly Tables:

The program is updated each month, and history save is required, therefore these tables are added EVERY MONTH.

**schedule_month_year** - The actual schedule.

```
id | datetime | teacherid
```

**requests_month_year** - Contains the requests from the teachers (I want a test on dd/mm, or I don't want on dd/mm)

```
id | teacherid | wantsornot
```

**teachers_month_year** - Contains information about teachers and how many tests they have for this month.

```
teacherid | tests
```

---

I'm looking for good advice here, maybe I initially wrote my code wrong, in which case, how do you write code preparing for events you don't know that might happen? (The code I currently have was already re-written nearly from scratch because I was requested to add a change too large to accommodate).

Comment: I know I don't like it either, but I didn't want to use HEADERS (SEO problems) so I used the most horrible way to attract attention :X

Comment: Its a good question. I think if you could post a diagram of your architecture or your database structure it would be easier to help you. There is no universal approach to do it (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I get the idea that *extensibility* is a hyped up buzzword. It’s not really. It does have merit. However, many touting the benefits of extensibility leave the impression that you can extend an application with virtually no work. This illusion falls apart in the face of database interactions because changes/additions to a database structure invariably necessitate changes in code. The truth behind extensible software is that it’s not *easy* to extend; rather, it’s *easier* than the alternative.

In this specific case, [Maxem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684700/extending-a-webapp-include-user-and-password/7685237#7685237) has the right idea. The fact that it "requires a change of all queries, which is quite a lot" is inconsequential. Since you have a working app, the extra work entails *only* those things required to extend it as opposed to a complete rewrite/redesign. If all you have to do is add some databases and change some queries, then you’re in a good position.

> how do you write code preparing for events you don't know that might
>   happen?

[Design principles](http://www.oodesign.com/design-principles.html) and patterns seek to answer this very question.

You may also benefit from [Agile software development](http://www.agile-process.org/) which addresses the issue of *changing requirements* among other things.

I believe experience also plays a crucial role here. In the future, when you design an app intended for a single user, you’ll instinctively start thinking about how it might be extended to multiple users and design the app accordingly. *Please understand that I’m not implying you’re inexperienced. My point here is that each new experience adds to your arsenal of techniques.*

Comment: Best answer by far so far. I'll wait another day or 2 to see further answers and I'll accept yours if no one is answering better.

Comment: Thanks for the booty (er... uh... bounty) @Truth. I can't think of anything that might improve my answer although I'm open to suggestions. Your question kind of gave me an excuse to rant a little. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> The point is to have each user a database for his own.

And why does that require any code change if every school is in its own database?

Anyways, what you have here is a typical multi tenant application. The usual way to go is to add the tenant identifier (in your case school) to more or less every table (class) and always filter by this tenant identifier.

Comment: I don't have each school in its own database, I want it to be that way :) and I though of that, but that also requires a change of all queries, which is quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have n + 1 databases.  (1 for the mapping of users to schools and
   the rest for the schools).
2. Create a database choosing class in your code.
3. Until a user is logged in use the mapping database.
4. When a user logs in retrieve their school and store it in the session.
5. Make the database choosing class use the correct database when the session is set.

Comment: +1, I would have done it the same way if I had limited time, but I think your description makes this simple solution sound difficult: "database choosing class", "mapping database" - really?  Sorry, maby it is just me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a table where each teacher belongs to a school and another table where each user belongs to a school. After the user logged in you get the user id, with the user id you get the school and with the school you get the teachers you need. Now you only pass those teachers to the webapp. IF you did everything right in advance, you should have some templates which you fill with the teacher and schedule content. Not only fill those templates with the content from the user.

Then you don't need one database for each user.

Comment: And what about the schedule itself? It's an entire list of datetimes and teacher IDs which define which teacher has what test, how can that be incorporated into a single database?

Comment: You can simply join the teacher ids in the schedule database with the teacher ids in the school and then you join the school id with the user. Then it is guaranteed that each user can't see a schedule outside of his school.